Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'globals' imported from eslint.config.mjs
I'm trying to setup a gitlab CI/CD with a linux runner. I'm running into some problems, first it couldn't find eslint as a command, after globally installing it it worked for some reason, but now I'm running into the problem that globals cannot be found. Can anyone help me with this issue? Here is my eslint.config.mjs:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import stylisticJs from '@stylistic/eslint-plugin-js'


/** @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config[]} */
export default [
  {
    files: ["src/**/*.js"],
    ignores: [
      "src/database/**/*"
    ],
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.node
      }
    },
    rules: {
      "prefer-const": "warn",
      "no-constant-binary-expression": "error",
      "camelcase": "error",
      "@stylistic/js/indent": ["error", 2],
      "@stylistic/js/object-curly-spacing": ["error", "never"],
      "@stylistic/js/quotes": ["error", "double"],
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    plugins: {'@stylistic/js': stylisticJs}
  },
];

And here is my gitlab-ci.yml file:
image: node:latest

stages:
  - install
  - lint
  - build

variables:
  NODE_ENV: production


install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - cd server
    - npm ci
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - server/node_modules/

eslint:
  stage: lint
  before_script:
    - cd server
    - npm ci
  script:
    - npm i -g eslint
    - npm i -g globals
    - npm run lint
  allow_failure: false
  

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd server
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
  dependencies:
    - install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - server/dist/

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: always

I dont know what to do right now. If you need any logs just ask me.

After adding artifacts to the lint step:
artifacts:
    paths:
      - server/node_modules/

the issues where resolved. I guess it has something to do with the server not finding what node_modules directory to use? I'm unsure I'm not a expert at gitlab CI/CD

delete the node modules and install them again it would work

Thanks for your comment however this is not the answer. It has something to do with the way of running commands on the gitlab server.
